# How would you translate the word 神祖?

Tags: translation

I can't find the word in my dictionary, and Google Translate translates it as 'ancestor' but I'm not sure how accurate that is.

I'm trying to translate this sentence:

> この葛葉家の屋敷で働く使用人はほぼ全員が一族の**神祖**であった『お狐様』を讃えるために狐の面をつけている。

However I'm not exactly sure what 神祖 means.

Comment: How are you looking this up? What have you found?

Comment: 国語辞典で調べてみられては？例えば→　https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/114851/meaning/m0u/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

神祖 is a rare word. There is only one instance of 神祖 in [BCCWJ](http://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/). So I won't be surprised if Google Translate and small dictionaries did not recognize this.

That said, the meaning of this word should be fairly straightforward if you know the meaning of each kanji.

- **神**: god; godly
- **祖**: ancestor; origin

So 神祖 refers to great/legendary ancestors in general. In this case it seems to literally refer to godly/divine ancestors, though.